# Error when running program with sharing library

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries

There is such code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <clang-c/Index.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CXIndex Index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(Index, 0, argv, argc, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
    for (unsigned I = 0, N = clang_getNumDiagnostics(TU); I != N; ++I)
    {
        CXDiagnostic Diag = clang_getDiagnostic(TU, I);
        CXString String = clang_formatDiagnostic(Diag,
                clang_defaultDiagnosticDisplayOptions());
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", clang_getCString(String));
        clang_disposeString(String);
    }
    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);

    clang_disposeIndex(Index);

    return 0;
}
```

And it's compiled with following flags:

```
g++ main.cpp -g -fno-rtti `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs` -lclang -o main
```

However when I want to run main:

```
./main
```

then there is following error:

```
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libclang.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However:

```
$ sudo find / -name libclang.so
/usr/local/lib/libclang.so
```

Library seems to be on place. How to run this program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ldconfig creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent
>   shared libraries found in the directories specified on the command
>   line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories
>   (/lib and /usr/lib)

Try running `/sbin/ldconfig` and then if that doesn't work try appending the file /etc/ld.so.conf with "/usr/local/lib" and then run `/sbin/ldconfig`

Commands:

1. Run the following command and then try compiling/running again

   /sbin/ldconfig
2. If that doesn't work then do this and then try compiling/running again

   echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
   /sbin/ldconfig